# Euler #4 Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers

Tags: c++

I am trying to make my program only select the largest product instead of all of them. 
P.S I know there are more efficient ways of doing this (such as taking out the duplicates) but I want to make it this way.

```
   #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isPal(int);

int main()
{
    int pal;
    // Finds largest product
    for (int a = 100; a < 1000; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 100; b < 1000; b++)
        {
            pal = a * b;
            if (isPal(pal))
            {
                cout << pal << "(" << a << "*" << b << ")" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


bool isPal(int num)
{
    bool status = true;
    int digit, rev = 0, ck_num; // Added new variable
    ck_num = num; // Assigned it to variable num

    // Tests for palindrome
    while (num)
    {
        digit = num % 10;
        num /= 10;
        rev = rev * 10 + digit;
    }

    if (rev == ck_num) // Checked it against unchanged variable
        status = true;
    else
        status = false;
    return status;

}
```

Comment: it would be better if you convert `number` to `string` and then testing for palindrome which is a lot faster than `multiplications` and `divisions` operations

Comment: Why are you counting **up** if you're looking for the **largest** palindrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a variable that stores the largest palindrome in it. And check each palindrome against it.

For example:

```
int largest = 0;

if (pal > largest) {
    largest = pal;
}
```

The if statement will go inside of "if (ispal(pal))" and you should create largest at the top of your program.
At the end of your program, you can display largest to see the answer.

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isPal(int);

int main()
{
    int largest;
    int pal;
    // Finds largest product
    for (int a = 100; a < 1000; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 100; b < 1000; b++)
        {
            pal = a * b;
            if (isPal(pal))
            {
                if (pal > largest) {
                    largest = pal;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Answer: " << largest << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's because you have coded it to do so. Remove the line `cout << pal...` and only print largest after the loop is over

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to identify a and b outside of the for loop so that I can display the numbers it took to get to the output?

Comment: Just create variables to store them in. Whenever you alter largest, change them too

Answer (score 0):

I’ve solved this one a few times in different languages.  Here’s my C solution.  It’s a fun one that gets a big speedup from some elementary number theory.  I’m probably not the first person to come up with this algorithm, but I came up with it independently.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

long euler4( long* const px, long* const py )
/* Finds the largest xy such that xy is a pal-
 * indrome, x and y are three-digit numbers,
 * and x*y = xy.
 */
{
/* We begin by enumerating the 900 possible
 * six-digit palindromes.
 */
  for ( long i = 9; i > 0; --i )
    for ( long j = 9; j >= 0; --j )
      for ( long k = 9; k >= 0; --k ) {
/* Any six-digit palindrome has the form
 * 100001i + 010010j + 001100k =
 *   11*(9091i+910j+100k)
 * Since 11 is prime, it must be a factor of
 * x or y.  Without loss of generality, let us
 * make it x.  We know that x must be at least
 * xy/999, at least 100, at most xy/100, at most
 * 999, and a multiple of 11.
 *
 * We could prune some more--for instance, xy
 * cannot be divisible by any prime between
 * 1000 and 999999/11=90909 if it is the
 * product of two three-digit factors--but I
 * don't see a way to improve performance by
 * doing so.
 */
        const long xy = 100001L*i+10010*j+1100*k;
        long x = xy/999+10;
        x = x - (x%11);
        x = (x > 110L) ? x : 110L;
        for ( ; x < 1000; x += 11 ) {
          const long y = xy/x;
          if ( y < 100 )
            break;
          if ( x*y == xy ) {
            *px = x;
            *py = y;
            return xy;
          } // end if
        } // end for x
      } // end for k

  fflush(stdout);
  fprintf( stderr, "No six-digit palindrome found.\n" );
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  return -1; // Not reached.
}

int main(void) {
  static const double MS_PER_TICK = 1000.0L / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  const clock_t start_time = clock();

  long x, y;
  const long xy = euler4(&x, &y);

  const clock_t end_time = clock();
  printf("Found %ld=%ld*%ld in %f ms.\n",
         xy, x, y, (end_time-start_time)*MS_PER_TICK
        );
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```